# Do ODATA READ query in a iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, odata

I am developing an application for iPad that need data from a ODATA service. The service provide a list of activities and each activities have details.

Firs I obtain the list of all activities between two dates (date_from and date_to). This list have an "id", "description", "date_from" and "date_to".

Code:

```
WindowsCredential *cred = [[[WindowsCredential alloc] initWithUserName:@"user" password:@"password"]autorelease];


    PROXY001 *proxy = [[PROXY001 alloc] initWithUri:@"http://ip:8000/odata/PROXY001/" credential:cred];

    DataServiceQuery *query =[proxy v1collection];
    [query filter:@"owner eq 'OWNER' and date_from eq '20120101' and date_to eq '20121231'"];

    QueryOperationResponse *response = [query execute];

    NSMutableArray *activities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    activities =[[response getResult] retain];


    for (int i=0; i<activities.count; i++) {


        v1collection *c = [activities objectAtIndex:i];

        //etc...

    }
```

But I need to get more details for each activity. To carry out this I have this uri:

```
http://ip:8000/odata/PROXY001/v1collection(binary'0050569C007D1ED1A8E615C3E1D843E1')
```

binary'0050569C007D1ED1A8E615C3E1D843E1' is an "id" of one activity.

The problem is that I don't know how do that with ObjectiveC.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
NSString *stringToExecute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1Collection(binary'%@')", guid];
QueryOperationResponse *response = [proxy execute:stringToExecute];
NSMutableArray *activitiesArray  = [response getResult];
Activities* activity = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Localization = %@", activity.getact_location);
```